# Xcode doesn't open the whole project

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.5

I have been working some days on this Xcode 4.5 ios project, but suddenly today when I tried to open the project it doesn't appear!! Only this view:

[image]

And I want the hole project window to show, like this:

[image]

PS: This image is from another project that opens the way I want it to.

What do I have to do to open the hole project editor window to edit the project normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go on View menu of XCode---> Show Tool Bars.

Then, press cmd+1 ( To show Navigator (left pane))

Comment: Thanks this solved my _silly_ problem!

Comment: It happens when you open a file from your project in this mode and closed the rest before quitting XCode, which is quite annoying...

Comment: @Larme : it happens when you open file, but is OP's case..see .***proj is visible, means he opened the project itself. SO I nailed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Move the split-view divider to the right?

[image]

Comment: I wished it was that simple